Mesh Collider button detects 60 clicks at once :(
I'm making a game that uses a bunch of different abstract shapes as provinces of a map. I attached mesh colliders along with a script to detect when the mesh is clicked. It's supposed to print to the console once but prints 62 times. I've tried a ton of different methods of writing the script and nothing is working please help!
This is my script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpaceButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera mainCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        // Get reference to the main camera
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check for mouse click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Cast a ray from the mouse position into the scene
            Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hitInfo;

            // Check if the ray hits a collider with a MeshCollider attached
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo) && hitInfo.collider is MeshCollider)
            {
                // Print the name of the GameObject that was clicked
                Debug.Log("Clicked on GameObject: " + hitInfo.collider.gameObject.name);

                
            }
        }
    }
}

My output is what was expected, just 60 more times than needed.

Im dumb ash the script was attached to multiple GameObjects in the scene, so multiple instances of the script were running simultaneously. Just had to change it so that it only activated the one that was clicked.

late to the party but yes, while the MouseButtonDown would limit it to 1 frame if you have 60 objects with the script on..
